# Working regex pattern doesn't work in PHP despite preg_quote

Tags: php, regex

The pattern below seems to work in regex editors, but it doesn't work in PHP (no error).
I thought by adding delimiters and running the pattern through preg_quote would address this.
Would appreciate any help on what step I'm missing here.

Code sample:

```
$pattern = '%(?<=@address|.)singleline(?=[^\]\[]*\])%';  
$pattern = preg_quote($pattern);
$output  = preg_replace($pattern, "", $output);
```

HTML Sample:

```
  <p>[@address|singleline]</p>
```

Comment: Can you add expected content of $output variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`preg_quote` escapes characters that are regular expression syntax characters.  These include `. \ + * ? [ ^ ] $ ( ) { } = ! < > | : -`.  Try not using `preg_quote`.

```
$pattern = '%(?<=@address|.)singleline(?=[^\]\[]*\])%';  
$output  = preg_replace($pattern, "", $output);
```

**EDIT:**
You might want to use `preg_quote` if you had content you wanted to include in your regex pattern which contained characters used in regex syntax.  For example:

```
$input = "item 1 -- total cost: $5.00";
$pattern = "/total cost: " . preg_quote("$5.00") . "/";
// $pattern should now be "/total cost: \$5.00/"
$output = preg_replace($pattern, 'five dollars', $input);
```

In this case, you need to escape the `$` because it is used in the regex syntax.  To search for it, your regex should use `\$` instead of `$`.  Using preg_quote  performs this alteration for you.

Comment: Thx. That worked...feel like an idiot for not thinking of it. So no need for preg_quote because everything was escape already?

Comment: Nothing needed to be escaped.  As @a.tereschenkov mentions, preg_quote would be relevant if you had some content in your pattern which needed to be escaped.  I'll edit my answer to give an example.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should apply preg_quote not for full pattern, bbut only for (maybe) external string. Look at this code:

```
<?php
    $content = 'singleline';
    $content = preg_quote($content);
    $output = '<p>[@address|singleline]</p>';
    $output  = preg_replace('%(?<=@address|.)'.$content.'(?=[^\]\[]*\])%', "", $output);

    echo $output;
```

As you can see I apply preg_quote only for $content variable (that might be with some characters which You need to escape)

Comment: Thx. been using method similar to that. For this question I just hard coded the variables.